# Why does OSGi select the service with lowest ID if the ID does not need to be ascending timewise?

Tags: java, osgi

I'm reading a book (OSGi in practice) and there is a part about the ranking of services which explains the rules which are used:

> The first is to look at a special **service.ranking** property on the services, which can be referenced in
>   code as `Constants.SERVICE_RANKING`. The value of the property is an integer
>   between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` (i.e. -2,147,483,648) and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`
>   (2,147,483,647). The service with the highest ranking is selected — services
>   that do not have an explicit ranking property take the implicit value of zero. If
>   this rule produces a tie, then the service with the lowest service **ID** is selected.
>   The second rule is somewhat arbitrary, but it tends to result in the “oldest”
>   service being selected, since in most framework implementation service IDs are
>   allocated from an incrementing counter (although this behaviour is not part
>   of the specification and cannot be relied upon).

Why does OSGi not enforce the ascending order (timewise) of service **ID** s?

Why does OSGi select the servcie with the lowest **ID** if their rank is the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Service IDs are assigned by the framework upon service registration. Each new id must be larger than all previously used ids (within that framework launch cycle). This is mandated by the OSGi specification. See section 5.2.5 in the Core spec (so I guess that book is wrong on this topic).

So a lower service id represents a service which was registered earlier than a service with a higher service id. So when ranking is equal, the earlier registered service is chosen.

Comment: The book says `this behaviour is not part of the specification and cannot be relied upon`.

Comment: The book is wrong. "Every registered service object is assigned a unique service.id by the Framework. This number is added to the service object’s properties. The Framework assigns a unique value to every registered service object that is larger than values provided to all previously registered service objects."